# Perl: sysopen() hangs while opening named pipe

Tags: perl, named-pipes

I'm using the following code to open a named pipe located at '/tmp/xyz' for read only access:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Fcntl;
...
sysopen(FIFO, "/tmp/xyz", O_RDONLY) or die ("opening named pipe failed: $!\n");
...
```

The problem is, that sysopen hangs upon calling. It neither 'dies' nor code after the call is executed.

output of ls -la /tmp/xyz:

```
prw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Jun 20 11:45 /tmp/xyz
```

Anybody got an idea, what's happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You opened it in blocking mode, program will not continue until someone writes into the FIFO.

You probably want to open it non-blocking:

```
O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK
```